# How can I run pdflatex on multiple .tex files on Windows 7?

Tags: macros, pdftex, luatex

I built some graphics with TikZ and pgfplots. I have put the code with the most minimal necessary preamble into a standalone document for each figure.

Say I put all those files for chapter 3 (hence the name Chap03_Something.tex) into the `main.tex`'s folder. Is there a way to run the engine of my choosing (most of the times that would be pdflatex, or LuaLaTeX a couple of times) on all files those `Chap03_*` **at once**?

Comment: If you have [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed, I think you can do something like: `for f in *.tex ; do engine-of-choice $f ; done`.  (Don't use Windows, however.)  However, I would recommend a Makefile if you have more complicated needs.

Comment: You can run for loop in DOS. This has nothing to do with latex really. Lookup FOR for dos for examples how to do it. Many examples on the net.

Comment: @Nasser Oh you are correct. Well, off I am to stackoverflow then. Hopefully I'll be returning with the answer. :)

Comment: Read the [standalone documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf) to see all options. Some of them allow automate this task.

Comment: @skpblack Oh, ok. Sounds great! Do you know if it can react to the respective processor/engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=D:\files\"
SET /p mask="Which .tex-files?"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%mask%*.tex" '
 ) DO (
 pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "%%a" any other parameters perhaps containing "%%~na"
 )
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Full credit goes to [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25289551/3181048), I just added the parameters `-interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape` for the use with pdflatex. If you know what "externalization" stands for in regards to TikZ/pgfplots and you use it, use  the code above as-is, otherwise **delete** the part `--shell-escape`.

For running another engine on the files, I copied the .bat-file and simply put `lualatex.exe` instead of `pdflatex.exe`. Of course the preamble must be organized accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make a exclusive directory for **pictures** and load in the *main document* with the command `\graphicspath{{./pictures/}}` of the package `graphics(x)`.

Create a batch file like

```
@echo off
echo "Processing images ..."
for %%i in (./*.tex) do pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %%i
echo "Deleting auxiliary files ..."
for %%i in (./*.aux) do del %%i
echo "Deleting log files ..."
for %%i in (./*.log) do del %%i
echo Done 
pause
```

and name it `pr_images.bat` for example and put it together with the `<imagefile_*>.tex` in  the **pictures** directory, then run it.

If you want to process with `lualatex` then edit the `.bat` file changing `pdflatex` by `lualatex`.

Now simply include the figures in the *main document* with `\includegraphics[<options>]{...}`. The `.bat` file must be inside of the **pictures** directory.

Comment: This is easier said than done since I have different preambles for the plots (with pgfplots) since I can't have all the `\pgfplotstableread`-commands commented out -> I need to have them commented out, most of the time. -> Different preambles.